# Pass argument to class decorator

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I'm trying add property with dynamic value to the class with TypeScript Decorator.
I use the following code from TS documentation :

```
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        newProperty = "new property";
        hello = "override";
    }
}
```

That's work but the value of these properties are not dynamic. Can we pass an argument to this function ? Like that :

```
@classDecorator('myArgument')
```

After that I would like to use `myArgument` in the html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorator is expression, that returns function. Expression can be function name itself (the we use it like `@classDecorator`), and can be call of the another function, that returns decorator function (then we use it like `@classDecorator('myArgument')`). Second approach looks like this:

```
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(myArgument:
 string) {
    return (constructor:T) => {
        return class extends constructor {
            newProperty = "new property";
            hello = "override";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, great, Thank your your help, that does what I want. :)